# Android where to store files

Tags: android, storage

Where should I store files for my app? My app is a home automation app for advanced users that will require them to upload images (floor plans, custom dashboards, etc) and xml configuration files to the phone. Where should I store them?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA, I hadn't thought of that. The files will regularly be updated and added to by the user. I wouldn't expect them to be too big. The config files will probably amount to less than 100K and the images wouldn't be more than about ten, all about the same size as what the camera would take natively. I don't think storing them on a server is an option. It needs to be on the device for sure. I was really thinking more like, in what folder on the device should I store these files.

Comment: @MrGribbage - Well, If you store them on the device, you are limited to only using folders in your apps current driectory, and even then you will have to created them. On the SDCard, it's really up to you. The docs say to use the Android/data/, but some many develpoers use their own folder that it doesn't matter. Really, I think you asking to broad and need to think more about what exactly do I need out of where I place my files, what are the reprecussions/benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how portable you want the files. Do you want the user to user them elsewhere (SDCard)? Do you want to back them up (Server)? Should the user never really care where they are (Device)? This really depends on how you want to use your files (or how the user may want to use your files).

Further, another thing to take into consideration it the file size. If they are huge, then the SDCard is the obvious choice.